# Make knob load after AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to get a knob animated right after my *ajax* call is done. I get a number, which the knob should `progress` to without a refresh. So what i want is: Ajax request is succesfull -> sends number to knob function -> the knob fill up.

Code:

```
..

success: function(data) {
    knobload(data);
}

..

function knobLoad(data) {
   $('.knob').each(function () {

       var $this = $(this);
       $this.knob({

       });
       $({
           value: 0
       }).animate({

           value: data
       }, {
           duration: 2000,
           easing: 'swing',
           step: function () {
               $this.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');

           }
       })

   });
}
</script>
<input class="knob animated" value="0" readonly data-width="80%">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up by adding the knob inside the file that the ajax requests, and then display it afterwards.

```
        $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                data: {
                    id: id

                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#knob').html(data);
                }
            });
```

The ajax file:

```
   $('.knob').each(function () {

       var $this = $(this);
       $this.knob({

       });
       $({
           value: 0
       }).animate({

           value: data
       }, {
           duration: 2000,
           easing: 'swing',
           step: function () {
               $this.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');

           }
       })

   });
</script>
<input class="knob animated" value="0" readonly data-width="80%">
```

Comment: Can you post your final solution?